# Apache Tomcat 9 fails to start (eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I've been using Apache Tomcat 7 for about a month with Eclipse and Java 1.8 and it has always worked well.
After upgrading to Java 10 I had problems with all the other versions so I reinstalled Eclipse and installed Apache Tomcat 9, thinking that having the server to the latest version was safer for my site.

Unfortunately now when I try to start the server I get this error:

```
apr 30, 2018 4:42:15 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap initClassLoaders
GRAVE: Class loader creation threw exception
java.io.IOException: La sintassi del nome del file, della directory o del volume non è corretta
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.File.getCanonicalFile(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory.createClassLoader(ClassLoaderFactory.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.createClassLoader(Bootstrap.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.initClassLoaders(Bootstrap.java:80)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:398)
```

I searched Google for finding few solutions and did not solve the problem.
Someone could explain to me how to solve?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by creating a system environment variable called CATA_HOME and I put the Apache Tomcat directory as a value.
I do not know why it always worked and suddenly stopped, but this solved the problem.
I hope it has been helpful to others with my same problem.